# "Command not found" piping a variable to cut when output stored in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, echo

In a bash script I am using a variable to hold a path like this:

```
MY_DIR=/just/a/string/to/my/path
```

And I want to remove the last two parts of it so it looks like this:

```
/just/a/string
```

I am using 'cut' to do it, like this:

```
echo $MY_DIR | cut -d'/' -f-4
```

The output is what I expect. Fine.
But I want to store in an other variable, like this:

```
MY_DIR2=$($MY_DIR | cut -d'/' -f-4)
```

When I execute the script I get the error:

```
... /just/a/string/to/my/path: No such file or directory
```

Why is the direct output with echo working, but storing the output in a variable is not?

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest `MY_DIR2=${MY_DIR%/*/*/*}` -- much more efficient than using `sed`. (Also, all-caps variable names are used by the shell and OS -- using lowercase names for your own variables avoids conflicts; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph).

Comment: Closed as dupe since the issue is (basically) that while you remembered the need to use `echo` on the standalone command, you forgot it in the command substitution -- so the problem, and the fix, is the same as in the flagged question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass an input string to the shell command using a pipeline in which case `cut` or any standard shell commands, reads from stdin and *acts* on it. Some of the ways you can do this are use a pipe-line

```
dir2=$(echo "$MY_DIR" | cut -d'/' -f-4)
```

(or) use a here-string which is a shell built-in instead of launching a external shell process

```
dir2=$(cut -d'/' -f-4 <<< "$MY_DIR")
```

Comment: I'm *positive* we've got duplicates for this in the knowledgebase.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I've done it for tons of similar questions before, but wanted to answer it, because of a decent attempt by someone trying to use the community for a first time

Comment: In a script, will this also work or not because of the subprocess? my cut is not working. The Here not working as well.

Comment: @Timo: What is not working? How you are running your code?

Comment: This was fast; li2=$(tr -d '\n' <<< "$li") running in a file.sh. or:         li=$(echo "$li" | tr -d '\n') I want to remove the \n in a line reading a file in bash.

Comment: What is present in `li`?

Comment: line ... <input [(ngModel)]="LastName \/>"
another .... [ngClass]="'main tall" --- later I want to replace substrings, it seems I have to switch to powershell or python. Bash is difficult.[here all](https://github.com/tik9/ml/blob/master/solu.sh)

Comment: @Timo: I suggest creating a separate question under bash tag for this. You are more likely to get help

Answer (score -1):

Use the grave accent(`) to emulate a command, and use echo too.

```
MY_DIR2=`echo $MY_DIR | cut -d'/' -f-4`
```

Comment: This is the old form of command substitution; `$()` is modern POSIX syntax, easier to nest, and doesn't change the way backslashes are interpreted within.

Comment: Also, it needs to be `echo "$MY_DIR"`, with the quotes -- otherwise a directory named `~/ * MY IMPORTANT FILES * /` would have the `*`s replaced with names of other directories.